# Next Auth continues to give "[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using Next-Auth in a next js website I am building. I have defined this in my .env

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=[secret]
```

however I am still getting the no secret warning every time I login. Does anyone know why this might be and if there is something I am missing? Thanks

Warning:

```
[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] 
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
```

Comment: Is this in production or development? Also how are you using the `env` and running your dev server? If you are running it via a build, you'll need to re-build it.

Comment: Was a development, I ended up figuring it out eventually was a issue with yarn.